# Socket Hang up while making multiple http post requests

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

I am reading a csv file and I am extracting data and making a post request every 30 seconds(setTimeout help) with data extracted with request module, after making 3 requests it shows this error

```
Error: socket hang up
 at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
 at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:292:23)
 at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
 at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
 at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation there could be multiple things that could cause this.

I would use something like [Async Parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) for these kind of tasks.
Give it a try.